# PHP, SCA_SDO, Ubuntu 14.04 unable to install

Tags: php, sdo

How i can install SDO on ubuntu 14.04? 
Like described here: http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.installation.php
i try pecl install SCA_SDO:

```
sudo pecl install SCA_SDO
....
194 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you need to install php5-dev packageYou can do it by running 'apt-get install php5-dev' as a root userERROR: `phpize' failed
```

m4 installed, php5-dev installed.
I try make phpize in folder with source and then ./configure make, but get error:

```
SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:569:5: note: in expansion of macro 'INIT_CLASS_ENTRY'
     INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(ce, "SDO_CPPException", sdo_cppexception_methods);
     ^
make: *** [sdo.lo] Error 1
```